vb.net 4.5.2 call api but receive status code 302 found without response how to solve
LocalHost can call api throws 200
vb.net 4.5.2 call api Post but receive status code 302 found without response how to solve
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: page.ashx,
            data: data, 
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            , statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                }, 500: function () {
                }
            }
        });

how to get response from call api 200

I assume the actual code has the value of the URL in quotes, or it's in a variable. Is it your own handler that is being called? If you send the request from a browser, you may be able to find out where the redirection should be going.
